# Do the speedrun badges count ingame time or real time?

Tags: shadow-tactics-blades-of-the-shogun

All of the missions in the game have an unlockable badge tied to a speedrun challenge, where you have to clear the mission withing a certain time limit. Seeing how often a player normally saves and reloads during the game, does the time limit account for that, or does it refer to real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those badges refer to real time, so saving and reloading a lot will use up time without making progress.

Answer (score 4):

DanmakuGrazer is mostly right, but its not really real time, because if you pause the game it will not continue the counter. It uses the amount of total ingame time you have spent playing, so if you save, play for 30 seconds, and then load, it still counts that 30 seconds.